# Synchronized InfoPath Attachment With Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, infopath, attachments

I have an InfoPath 2010 form with a Document attachment.

- if any user upload infopath form with attachment, than attachment must be added in document library,
- if any user modify or delete any attachment form infopath library than that document must be update or delete from document library.

**- if any user modify or delete any document(s) in document library then that document(s) must be update / delete in infopath form attachment also.**

Can anyone guide me how can I perform this using C# programmatically

Thanks in Advance

Kapil Dave